# An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, salesforce, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to access Salesforce data from visual studio. But the code returns the above exception.
My class file is given below.

```
     public string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";

            // Add parameters to post
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
            req.ContentLength = data.Length;
            System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            os.Close();

            // Do the post and get the response.
             **System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();**
                if (resp == null) return null;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
 }
```

I am trying to invoke the POST methode to retrieve token from salesforce. The statement enclosed by '**' throws exception.

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: catch the exception and look at the response body, it'll have more info about why the request failed. Its hard to say more about why it might not be working unless you provide the URI & params values you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't at all clear what data you are trying to post to Salesforce or what URL you are using. Is this a custom web service you are trying to submit data to or something like web 2 lead?

A fairly standard way to integrate Salesforce with .NET is via the [Partner API or the Enterprise API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm). Those are usually good starting points and have defined WSDLs that you can import into a Visual Studio project as a web reference.

There are also various [REST apis](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/). Since you are posting to

> "login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"

I'm assuming your using the [Web Server OAuth 2 Authentication Flow](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) and that you have the authorization code which you are now using to request an access token.

The parameters that you post to this URL should look something like (Note, this is taken directly from the Salesforce data so it shouldn't contain any sensitive information):

> **grant_type**=authorization_code&**code**=aPrxsmIEeqM9PiQroGEWx1UiMQd95_5JUZ
>   VEhsOFhS8EVvbfYBBJli2W5fn3zbo.8hojaNW_1g%3D%3D&**client_id**=3MVG9lKcPoNI
>   NVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCs
>   cA9GE&**client_secret**=1955279925675241571&
>   **redirect_uri**=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fcode_callback.jsp

You will want to use the authorization code that Salesforce returned to you in the previous step and your own client_id and client_secret. You can also set the redirect_uri as you please.

---

To establish the REST connection with a username and password: [Understanding the Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm)

You will want to set the grant_type to password and provide the username and password. This should be posted to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

> **grant_type**=password&**client_id**=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82Hn
>   FVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&**client_secret**=
>   1955279925675241571&**username**=testuser%40salesforce.com&**password**=mypassword123456

You can then get the `access_token` from the response.

Comment: I am using rest api. The url used is follows, string URI = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

Comment: It appears you are following the example from [Salesforce.com REST API](http://danlb.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/salesforcecom-rest-api.html), correct?

Comment: Yes,that is correct. But i don't have authorization code. Can you give an example for grand type as password?

Comment: @user3065219 I've expanded the answer to include a grant_type of password.

Comment: @user3065219 By the way, the http://salesforce.stackexchange.com site is a great place for Salesforce specific questions.